# WildFly - How To View Deployment

Tags: java, jboss, wildfly

This may be a stupid question, but I've been scouring the documentation and I can't seem to come up with an answer. I've deployed a WAR file through the web interface in WildFly, but how do I view this deployment? In Tomcat it would be something like http://:8080/mydeploymentname, but I can't find something similar for WildFly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can look at the web admin console http://:9990.
If you can't access your deployed war, it may also mean that there was an issue during deployment, so you should look at the logs, too (in (server_base)/standalone/log)

Comment: what was the problem? Wrong address or an issue during deployment?